# Joining table not directly related to main table in cakephp

Tags: sql, cakephp, has-one

I have three tables whose structure is is similar to below :

```
employees    offices    postings
________   ________  ___________
id           id       employees_id  
name         name     offices_id
```

So I want to know how can I get the office name from Employee model. Putting `office` within `$hasOne` array `shows Unknown column 'office.employees_id' in 'on clause'`. What should I do to get the office name in the results ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to stick to your database, you might use has and belongs to many relation.
In employee.php:

```
   public $hasAndBelongsToMany = [
       'Office'=> [
            'foreign_key' => 'employees_id',
            'joinTable' => 'postings',
            'associationForeignKey' => 'offices_id',
       ]
   ];
```

Then you can get office from employee model.

What I really want to suggest is that put a column `office_id` in `employees` table, and put

```
$public $belongsTo = ['office'];
```

in your employee model.

PS: Brackets `[]` is supported in php 5.4 or newer , if you are using php 5.3 or lower, you may want to replace it with `array()`.